# How to add lower function to this code

Tags: python

I want to print my output in lowercase, but I am not getting the correct results. Here's my code. Please help!

```
import csv
mags = csv.reader(open("mags.csv","rU"))

for row in mags:


     print [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]

     print [item.lower( ) for item in row]
```

Comment: What results are you getting and how do those differ from what you want?

Comment: The problem is that I get 2 outputs for each row in the CSV. The 1st print statement returns the data in the desired sequence, and the 2nd print statement returns the same data in lowercase. What I want is to merge these two outputs, but I am not sure how to code it.

Comment: Do you want them all in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the two comprehensions like this:

```
print [item.lower() for item in [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]]
```

That way you'll use the data from the first comprehension (the second and first item of the row in this order) as input for the second one (lowercase everything).

You can also slice the row instead of using a comprehension for the first one:

```
 print [item.lower() for item in row[::-1][-2:]] # Slicing in 2 steps: [::-1] reverses the list and [-2:] returns the last two items of the reversed list
```

or (Shorter, but reversed indices slicing doesn't work as you'd think)

```
 print [item.lower() for item in row[1::-1] # Same thing, but it helps to break these things up into steps
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension can be nested, like so

```
print [item.lower() for item in [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]]
```

Don't have an interpreter handy to test this, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the row is a list of strings here ?
I see correct output :

```
>>> row = [ "alpA", "bETA","gammA" ]
>>> print [item.lower( ) for item in row]
['alpa', 'beta', 'gamma']
>>>
```